# Getting information about which column belongs to which table using TSql120Parser

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am building a SQL query parser using `TSql120Parser` (`Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom`) and as mechanics are fairly simple, break query into batches and getting information from proper statements.

I have a problem how to join columns from select statement to tables from select statement, lets use simple query:

```
SELECT 
    capture_instance as TableName
    , supports_net_changes as SupportNetChanges
    , index_name as PrimaryKeyName 
FROM 
    cdc.change_tables as ChangeTables
```

I am breaking query to statements like:

```
    public void Parse(string query)
    {
        ColumnListInfo = new ColumnInfoList();

        IList<ParseError> parseErrors;
        TSqlFragment result = _sqlParser.Parse(new StringReader(query), out parseErrors);

        if (parseErrors.Any())
        {
            throw new AggregateException(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, parseErrors.SelectMany(error => $"Error: {error.Message}").ToArray()));
        }

        var sqlScript = (TSqlScript)result;
        foreach (TSqlStatement sqlStatement in sqlScript.Batches.SelectMany(sqlBatch => sqlBatch.Statements))
        {
            if (sqlStatement.GetType() == typeof(SelectStatement))
            {
                ProcessSqlSelectStatement(sqlStatement);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"Query type not supported: {sqlStatement.GetType()}");
            }
        }
    }
```

Next I am getting information about select statement and from statements:

```
    private void GenerateSelectInfo(QuerySpecification querySpecification)
    {
        int selectElementId = 0;

        foreach (SelectElement selectElement in querySpecification.SelectElements)
        {
            if (selectElement.GetType() != typeof (SelectScalarExpression)) continue;

            SelectScalarExpression selectScalarExpression = (SelectScalarExpression)selectElement;
            IdentifierOrValueExpression identifierOrValueExpression = selectScalarExpression.ColumnName;
            var identityString = string.Empty;

            if (identifierOrValueExpression != null)
            {
                if (identifierOrValueExpression.ValueExpression == null)
                {
                    identityString = identifierOrValueExpression.Identifier.Value;
                }
                ColumnListInfo.AddIfNeeded(selectElementId, identityString);

                ScalarExpression scalarExpression = selectScalarExpression.Expression;
                GenerateSelectScalarExperssionRecurse(selectElementId, scalarExpression);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Error, something else than SelectScalarExpression found");
            }

            selectElementId++;
        }
    }
    private void GenerateReferenceRecurse(TableReference tableReference)
    {
        if (tableReference.GetType() == typeof(NamedTableReference))
        {
            var namedTableReference = (NamedTableReference)tableReference;
            Identifier aliasIdentifier = namedTableReference.Alias;
            SchemaObjectName schemaObjectName = namedTableReference.SchemaObject;
            ColumnListInfo.AddTableReference(schemaObjectName, aliasIdentifier);
        }
        else if (tableReference.GetType() == typeof(SchemaObjectFunctionTableReference))
        {
            var namedTableReference = (SchemaObjectFunctionTableReference)tableReference;
            Identifier aliasIdentifier = namedTableReference.Alias;
            SchemaObjectName schemaObjectName = namedTableReference.SchemaObject;
            ColumnListInfo.AddTableReference(schemaObjectName, aliasIdentifier);
        }
        else if (tableReference.GetType() == typeof(QualifiedJoin))
        {
            QualifiedJoin qualifiedJoin = (QualifiedJoin)tableReference;
            GenerateReferenceRecurse(qualifiedJoin.FirstTableReference);
            GenerateReferenceRecurse(qualifiedJoin.SecondTableReference);
        }
        else if (tableReference.GetType() == typeof(JoinTableReference))
        {
            JoinTableReference joinTableReference = (JoinTableReference)tableReference;
            GenerateReferenceRecurse(joinTableReference.FirstTableReference);
            GenerateReferenceRecurse(joinTableReference.SecondTableReference);

        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Not supported table reference : {tableReference.GetType()}");
        }
    }

    private void GenerateSelectScalarExperssionRecurse(int selectElementId, ScalarExpression scalarExpression)
    {
        if (scalarExpression.GetType() == typeof(ColumnReferenceExpression))
        {
            ColumnReferenceExpression columnReferenceExpression = (ColumnReferenceExpression)scalarExpression;
            MultiPartIdentifier multiPartIdentifier = columnReferenceExpression.MultiPartIdentifier;
            ColumnListInfo.AddRefereceIdentifier(selectElementId, multiPartIdentifier);
        }
        else if (scalarExpression.GetType() == typeof(ConvertCall))
        {
            ConvertCall convertCall = (ConvertCall)scalarExpression;
            ScalarExpression scalarExpressionParameter = convertCall.Parameter;
            GenerateSelectScalarExperssionRecurse(selectElementId, scalarExpressionParameter);
        }
        else if (scalarExpression.GetType() == typeof(FunctionCall))
        {
            FunctionCall functionCall = (FunctionCall)scalarExpression;
            Identifier functionIdentifier = functionCall.FunctionName;
            ColumnListInfo.AddFunctionIdentifier(selectElementId, functionIdentifier);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Not supported Expression: {scalarExpression.GetType()}");
        }
    }
```

I am using a recursive method as if there are any joins from which I can get table information

But now I do not know hot to combine information of which table goes with which columns, I tried:

```
        public void AddTableReference(SchemaObjectName schemaObjectName, Identifier aliasIdentifier)
        {
            if (ColumnList.Count <= 0) return;

            foreach (ColumnInfo columnInfo in ColumnList)
            {
                if (aliasIdentifier != null &&
                    string.Equals(columnInfo.TableAlias, aliasIdentifier.Value, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    if (schemaObjectName.SchemaIdentifier != null) columnInfo.TableSchema = schemaObjectName.SchemaIdentifier.Value;
                    if (schemaObjectName.BaseIdentifier != null) columnInfo.TableName = schemaObjectName.BaseIdentifier.Value;
                }
                else if (aliasIdentifier == null && schemaObjectName.BaseIdentifier != null &&
                         string.Equals(schemaObjectName.BaseIdentifier.Value, columnInfo.TableAlias, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    if (schemaObjectName.SchemaIdentifier != null) columnInfo.TableSchema = schemaObjectName.SchemaIdentifier.Value;
                    if (schemaObjectName.BaseIdentifier != null) columnInfo.TableName = schemaObjectName.BaseIdentifier.Value;
                }
            }
        }
```

But this works only on join columns, is there a way??

Comment: When the column names aren't prefixed by a table name or alias, you (and indeed SQL Server) cannot determine this information *purely* from parsing. You need to query the database metadata to determine which of the tables in scope within the query contains a column with the given name (and to raise an error if multiple tables contain columns with the same name)

Comment: Multiple **typo alerts**: it's a **statement** - not a "statesmen" - it's a **column** (not a "collumn" - one "l" is quite enough) - and a "witch" is a old, ugly lady on a broomstick - what you want is **which**

Comment: And stupid auto correct plug in

Comment: Hi Wojciech, I am also working on the parsing sql queries specifically large Views. My skill is intermediate in C# programming. I am trying to build the code base to understand the joins tables and joins columns. Could you provide copy to your code base for reference it will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: It has been a while. When and if I will find it of course I will share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Damien_The_Unbeliever mentioned:

> Blockquote
>   When the column names aren't prefixed by a table name or alias, you (and indeed SQL Server) cannot determine this information purely from parsing. You need to query the database metadata to determine which of the tables in scope within the query contains a column with the given name (and to raise an error if multiple tables contain columns with the same name)